# Access UINavigationController From AppDelegate

Tags: swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I need to access `UINavigationController` in `AppDelegate`

Here is what I tried

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let syncManager = SyncManager()
    let navigationController: UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(
        name: "Main",
        bundle: nil
    ).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
    syncManager.setNavigationController(navigationController)
    syncManager.sync()
}
```

This doesn't seem to work.

How do I access `UINavigationController` from the `AppDelegate`?

Thanks.

**Update**

I am using this [library](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Whisper) to display the notification in the application when the app is active. this library requires an instance of navigationController to display the notification.

When I use this code in `AppDelegate` the notification is not displayed, but when I use in the in `ViewController` the notifications are displayed.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: No error message, but it does not work as well. Basically I am using a notification display which requires the instance of navigaitonController. When I use this code, the notification does not display at all. But when I directly use the instance of navigaitonController from viewController it works. let me update my question with more clarity.

Comment: A standard `UINavigationController` actually nothing without `UIViewController`. It's only can navigate and manage their `viewControllers`.

Comment: does `UIWindow`'s `rootViewController` not work for you? how does your view-hierarchy look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

let navigationController = application.windows.first?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController

it wont crash even if your rootViewController is TabBarController . it will safely unwrap it .